# Как подключить Ubuntu Server 15.04 к Wi-Fi по WPA2-PSK?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Пытаюсь подружить Ubuntu Server 15.04 с Wi-Fi.
Выполнение команды:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid MyNet key s:mypassword
```

Приводит к ошибке:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот нашел рабочее решение проблемы http://sudouser.com/podrobnoe-rukovodstvo-po-nastrojke-wifi-soedineniya-s-shifrovaniem-raznyx-tipov.html

Открываем редактором файл **/etc/network/interfaces** и пишем в него следующее:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ssid <имя_вашей_точки_доступа>
wpa-ap-scan 1
wpa-proto RSN
wpa-pairwise CCMP
wpa-group CCMP
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk <ваш_ключ_от_точки_доступа>
```

Далее просто перезапускаем:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Добавьте в ответ, хотя бы вкратце, что именно вам помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй заменить key на enc. Видимо ТД защищен psk2, а не wep. Затем dhclient wlan0.
Если не получается попробуй [wpa-supplicant](http://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant).